# Lumen server integration with php-my-admin instance

Tags: php, mysql, server, phpmyadmin, lumen

I'm loading my lumen project on a server that already has a php-my-admin instance loaded onto it.
After the project loading the php-my-admin panel becomes unreachable.
I'd like to keep using that istance with the lumen project, i have found some people talking about php-myadmin and Laravel set-up but can't find a specific one for the lumen-php-my-admin setup.

P.S the server isn't mine so i can't fiddle too much with it

Comment: Are you installing Lumen to the same directory that already has phpMyAdmin in it? Do you have access to configure the web server (Apache, Nginx, etc)?

Comment: No i don't think it is the same directory, it is a standard ubuntu server with phpmyadmin installed but after the lumen upload it becomes unreachable